# counting sort with strings [core dumped]

Tags: c, sorting

i need to write a counting sort algorithm which is sorting strings by the first letter (it doesn't matter if it's capital or small), but there is a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error after writing all strings. There are also some warnings (below)

```
aaa.c: In function ‘Count’:
aaa.c:20:23: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
           C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);
                       ^
aaa.c:20:33: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
           C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);
                                 ^
aaa.c:20:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);
               ^
aaa.c:22:25: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                B[(int)C[(int)A[j]]]=A[j];
                         ^
aaa.c:22:18: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                B[(int)C[(int)A[j]]]=A[j];
                  ^
aaa.c:23:18: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                C[(int)A[j]]=C[(int)A[j]]-1;
                  ^
aaa.c:23:31: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
                C[(int)A[j]]=C[(int)A[j]]-1;


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MaxStringLength 30
#define MaxStringNumber 5
#define NumberOfLetters 26

char **A;
char **B;
char **C;

void Count(char **A, char **B, int quantity){
        int i,j;

        for (i=1;i<=NumberOfLetters;i++) C[i]=0;
        for (j=1;j<=quantity;j++)
             C[A[j][1]-96] +=1;
        for (i=2;i<=NumberOfLetters;i++)
          C[i]=(char)((int)C[i]+(int)C[i-1]);     
        for (j=MaxStringNumber;j>0;j--){
               B[(int)C[(int)A[j]]]=A[j]; 
               C[(int)A[j]]=C[(int)A[j]]-1;

        }
}

void printing(char **array, int quantity){
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=quantity;i++)
                printf("%s \n", array[i]);
}

void reading(char **array, int quantity){
        char word[MaxStringLength];
        int i;
        for (i=1;i<=quantity; i++){
                scanf("%s",word);
                array[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*MaxStringLength);
                strcpy(array[i],word);
        }
}

int main(){
        A=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber+1)*sizeof(char*));
        B=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber+1)*sizeof(char*));
        C=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber+1)*sizeof(char*));

        printf("Array A:\n");
        reading(A,MaxStringNumber);
        Count(A,B,MaxStringNumber);
        printf("Sorted:\n");
        printing(B,MaxStringNumber);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fix the warnings. A small program like this should never have any warnings. `C[(int)A[j]]`. What do you expect to achieve by using a pointer as an array index?

Comment: The program does not even begin to make sense. I'd recommend starting with the absolute basics of C. @kaylum I'd be more concerned by using a `char` as a pointer.

Comment: The way you've written this code - using global variables for A, B, and C; having magic numbers like 96 and short names like A, B, and C;  and using 1-indexing in the array - all likely contribute to why you're running into issues here. I think that you may want to restructure this code to avoid global variables and use more expressive names to make things clearer.

Comment: @kaylum i was trying to implement this algorithm http://lifehug.com/category/algorithms/ with strings, but as you can see i have some problems with understanding how to do it. any suggestions how the Count function should look like?

Comment: The suggestion is to go back and learn the fundamentals of C. Your code has too many basic errors in it which indicates you are not ready to attempt this right now. Start with something simpler and work your way to more complex code as you master each step.

Comment: there are only pointer/array problems so i don't think that this is too advanced for now

Comment: @bardamu: you have more bugs than you have lines of code, so I think maybe it *is* a little too advanced for you at the moment, and you should take the good advice above and get a simpler program working first to help you understand some of the basics. We all have to start somewhere...

Comment: @barmadu - Welcome back. I see this is a repost of yesterdays question with a simpel cast to fix the fatal compile errors. As I said at the time, that was almost certianly not the correct fix, and it turns out that it isnt. First thing to do, change the names of A,B,C to say what they actually mean, people might then be able to work out what you are tyring to do

Comment: @bardamu - is this homework, or are you trying to follow an example from a textbook? If it's homework, we can only offer suggestions. If it's not homework, I can post a fixed example. C should be int * (array of integers), not char ** (array of pointers to strings). In C index range is 0 to size-1, not 1 to size. This affects the indexing and the for loops.

Comment: @rcgldr example from classes, but it's not a homework

Comment: @bardamu - ok, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As commented there were several problems with the original code. In C indices go from 0 to size-1, not from 1 to size. C[] needs to be an array of integers (or size_t). The initial and ending values for loops and the end of loop checks such as < or <= needed to be fixed.

Since the amount of back and forth to correct one error at time would take too long, I created a working example.

This example is working but assumes input is exactly 5 lines and all characters are lower case. The -96 converts 'a' into 1, 'b' into 2, ... . So after generating counts, C[0] = 0, C[1] = count of 'a', C[2] = count of 'b', ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MaxStringLength 30
#define MaxStringNumber 5
#define NumberOfLetters 26

void Count(char **A, char **B, int *C, int quantity){
int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<NumberOfLetters;i++) C[i]=0;
    for (j=0;j<quantity;j++)
         C[A[j][0]-96]++;
    for (i=1;i<=NumberOfLetters;i++)
        C[i] += C[i-1];
    for (j=MaxStringNumber-1;j>=0;j--)
        B[--C[A[j][0]-96]]=A[j]; 
}

void printing(char **array, int quantity){
int i;
    for (i=0;i<quantity;i++)
    printf("%s \n", array[i]);
}

void reading(char **array, int quantity){
char word[MaxStringLength+1];
int i;
    for (i=0;i<quantity; i++){
        scanf("%s",word);
        array[i] = (char*) malloc(MaxStringLength+1);
        strcpy(array[i],word);
    }
}

int main(){
char **A;
char **B;
int   *C;
    A=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber)*sizeof(char**));
    B=(char**) malloc((MaxStringNumber)*sizeof(char**));
    C=(int *)  malloc((NumberOfLetters+1)*sizeof(int *));

    reading(A,MaxStringNumber);
    printf("Array A:\n");
    printing(A,MaxStringNumber);
    Count(A,B,C,MaxStringNumber);
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    printing(B,MaxStringNumber);
    /* clean up */
    for(i = 0; i < MaxStringNumber; i++)
        free(B[i]);     /* or A[i] */
    free(C);
    free(B);
    free(A);
    return 0;
}
```